# Arguments of functions

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, prototype

Tell me how to determine the amount of function's arguments.

For example:

```
var func1 = function(arg1, arg2){};
var func2 = function(agr1, arg2, arg3){};

var i1 = myargscounter(func1); // = 2
var i2 = myargscounter(func1); // = 3
```

myargscounter - unknown algorithm that I need

Comment: a function has a length property - does that help? `const myargscounter = fn => fn.length;`

Comment: @DroidNoob but that's the number passed, not the number defined.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks, just realized. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) for this:

```
var func1 = function(arg1, arg2){};
var func2 = function(agr1, arg2, arg3){};

function myargscounter(func) {
  return func.length;
}

var i1 = myargscounter(func1); // = 2
var i2 = myargscounter(func2); // = 3

console.log(i1);
console.log(i2);
```

Comment: If someone is to downvote, it would be great to provide some sort of feedback, as the answer is correct from a technical point of view.